# Study of a vector field

Tags: python, 3d, vector-graphics, graphic, mayavi

I have an input data with 6 columns where the three first are the position x, y, z and the rest are vector components of a vector field. I could only make a 3d graph with quiver3d of the mayavi library in python (x,y,z,px,py,pz) creating 6 numpy arrays x,y,z,px,py,pz just to visualize it.

It would be great to get a 3D graph by any mean where I could insert cut planes where the vectors that are contained on it would be shown, or planes where I could see a color map that would help me to understand its beahaviour. Any help?

Here is the input:
    https://pastebin.com/raw/pmGguxUc

Here is the code I used to get the visualization with quiver3d function.
    import numpy as np
    import mayavi.mlab as mlab

```
data = np.loadtxt("vectorfield.dat", dtype = float)
dataTranspuesta=data.T
x=dataTranspuesta[0]
y=dataTranspuesta[1]
z=dataTranspuesta[2]
px=dataTranspuesta[3]
py=dataTranspuesta[4]
pz=dataTranspuesta[5]

mlab.quiver3d(x, y, z, px, py, pz, line_width=0.7 ,scale_mode="vector" ,scale_factor=0.0045,mask_points=7 ,mode="arrow", colormap="seismic" )
mlab.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to organize everything using mayavi's pipeline. They are basically the same as using mlab plotting functions, but organize your visualization tasks in a pipeline fashion.

```
Pfld = mlab.pipeline.vector_field(x, y, z, px, py, pz)
Quiver = mlab.pipeline.vectors(Pfld)
Pcut = mlab.pipeline.vector_cut_plane(Quiver, plane_orientation='x_axes')
```

You can also draw isosurface contours for the vectors' magnitude

```
Pmag = mlab.pipeline.extract_vector_norm(Pfld)
Piso = mlab.pipeline.iso_surface(Pmag)
```

and plane cuts of the scalar field can be achieved through `mlab.pipeline.scalar_cut_plane(Pmag)` or `mlab.pipeline.image_plane_widget(Pmag)`

See [documentations](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_pipeline_other_functions.html#) for more details on the allowed arguments, decorations, etc.

Also [examples 1](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/mlab.html#id3) and 
[exmaples 2](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/3d_plotting/auto_examples/visualize_field.html) may fit your needs.